# Find Key for a given value in dictionary, where the value can be a list

Tags: python, dictionary, key

i would like to identify a key of a dictionary, if a certain value is contained in the value, which itself can be a list. I tested the following code:

```
   h={"Hi":[1,2],"du":3}

for book, product in h.items():
    if 1 in product:
               print(book)
```

and it gives me the error

```
 if 1 in product:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Cant figure out what is wrong here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why didn't you create `h` with the value `[3]` for the `'du'` key? I think that was your mistake

Comment: @Chris_Rands that seems to be a better way to go, probably OP could've missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in one of the iterations, specifically when `book` is `"du"`, `product` is `3`, which is an `int`, not a `list`, and therefore is not iterable. You should check first if `product` is a list. If it is, check if 1 is in it; if it's not, check if it's equal to 1.

```
h={"Hi":[1,2],"du":3,"nn":1}
for book, product in h.items():
    if (isinstance(product, list) and 1 in product) or product == 1:
        print(book)  # prints both "Hi" and "nn"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first check whether it is a `list`:

```
if isinstance(product, list) and 1 in product:
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an error, because `3` (the value of `"du"`) is not a list.

Simply add a check if the item is indeed an instance of type list:

```
h={"Hi":[1,2],"du":3}

for book, product in h.items():
    if isinstance(product, list):
        if 1 in product:
            print(book)
```